# Where to direct people for support if they can't log in to beta despite being committers?

Tags: support

I've spoken to a [number](https://twitter.com/elliotlewis/status/271544221331238912) of [people](https://twitter.com/jimpannell/status/271382258395541504) (there are more besides) on Twitter who committed to the proposal but have found that they are unable to log in due to StackExchange's Byzantine/Kafkaesque login system.

The "contact us" and "feedback" links on [the login page](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/login) just redirect to the login page - winning at UX guys!

Where can I direct these people to get help gaining access? They are champing at the bit to contribute to this community, but instead are getting annoyed and becoming *less* likely to contribute... Mods please help us to help ourselves!

Comment: +1 for obscure references I had to google

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is just send the users a direct invite. If you get their email address you should be able to send them a link. Unfortunately they'll have to use Open ID. Strongly encourage them to use the same login they used while committing or link their accounts.

The login/signup process sucks, but we're not in a really good position to argue the point with SE.

Comment: I've sent out about 4+ invites, mostly to people which said they were part of the commitment stage, who I found on Twitter who were having login issues. I asked them to DM me their email addresses which of course isn't all that private and then I sent them the invite using the form provided in the sidebar of our beta. It works though, not ideal by any means.